# What's my status in Thailand after being fired?

Tags: visa

I was hired in June by a small English center here. The owner turned out to be totally corrupt, registering me at another school so she could avoid various fees and bribes, and lying to me about the nature of the job before I moved here.

We clashed over these things and because of her very rude, bullying manner. She fired me recently and told me she'll cancel my work permit in a month; that I have to go to Immigration with various documents to cancel my non-Immigrant B visa; and that I have to leave the country as soon as that work permit is invalidated.

However, my non-immigrant B visa is valid till the end of September. Can I stay here until then without risk while I seek another job? What if I don't go to Immigration to cancel that visa? And what are the most effective ways to report and bring to justice this criminal?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Where is "here", and where are you from?

Comment: Here is Bangkok.

Answer (score 3):

If your employer reported you to Immigration, your visa isn't valid anymore, and you have to leave Thailand. There is very little you can do.

You could consult a lawyer, but I'm afraid it won't help much, and cost you money for naught. If you can find a job quickly, your new employer *might* be able to sponsor you and get you a new visa. But in any case you need a new one.

Remember, Thailand is very corrupt, and a Thai vs Farang dispute always ends the same way.